# How do I call a function when UINavigationController UINavigationTabBar Item is tapped?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to be able to present a UIAlertAction when the user taps a UINavigationController UINavigationTabBar Item to remind them they need to enter some information before they can proceed to the next UIViewController that would otherwise be called from such a tap. The code that is called from the tap would check if an array is empty, if so, then display the UIAlertAction.

I've tried to create an instance of the UINavigationController's UINavigationTabBar item, to try and detect it being pushed, but this is messy as the UIViewController to be called has already been setup as a segue when the UINavigationTabBar item is tapped.

Do I need to backtrack and remove the existing segue and create the transition in a different way that allows my desired array checking code to be callable on the user's tap?

Comment: So you configured the appearing with a segue?

Comment: What is a `UINavigationTabBar`? There is no such thing. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you really mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pushing the next view controller using a segue, you would intercept that segue, do all your checks, and then inform the segue whether to go on or cancel the pushing. Basically in your view controller:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "NextViewControllerID" {
        var isValid = true

        // example of validation, do your stuff here
        if myTextField.text?.count ?? 0 < 5 {
            isValid = false
        }

        return isValid
    }
    // otherwise delegates the superclass
    return super.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: I've made identifier = Words (segue next view controller id in storyboard, words being related to the next view controller to segue to). Just not sure about 'withIdentifier:' Segue happens even when validation is false (an empty array).

Comment: Be sure you return false if validation is not ok

Comment: returns false when array is empty, returns true is identifier is segue identifier of next view controller. I don't think the boolean is the problem.

Comment: If you return true if the identifier is of the view controller to go to, it’s obvious that the segue is triggered. Post your new code please

Comment: override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "Words" {
            var isValid = true
            if languages.isEmpty == true {
                isValid = false
            }
            
            return isValid
        }
        // otherwise delegates the superclass
        return super.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
    }

Comment: It works for me, edit your answer and put your whole view controller, maybe there's something else we're missing

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class WordsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // write button selector method to check if there are any words.

    var words = [String]()
    var languages = [String]()
    var chosenLanguage = String()
    var textField: UITextField?
    let wordString = "Words"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chosenLanguageLoad()
        loadInitialValues()

        //let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 22)!]
        //navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(test))

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewWord))

        print("languages array is: \(languages)")
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "Words" {
            print("inside identifier == words if")
            var isValid = true
            if languages.isEmpty == true {
                print("languages is empty is true")
                isValid = false
            }

            return isValid
        }
        // otherwise delegates the superclass
        return super.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
    }

    @objc func test() {
        if words.isEmpty == true {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add Some Words", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
            ac.addAction(okAction)
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Test", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func chosenLanguageLoad() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.polyglot") {
            if let loadChosenLanguage = defaults.object(forKey: "languageChosen") as? String {
                chosenLanguage = loadChosenLanguage
                print("Chosen language is: \(chosenLanguage)")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func loadInitialValues() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.polyglot") {
            words.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()
            print("Words array after clear all: \(words)")
            print("chosenLanguage in loadInitialValues: \(chosenLanguage)")
            print("\(chosenLanguage)\(wordString)")
            if var savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "\(chosenLanguage)\(wordString)") as? [String] {
                print("savedWords array is: \(savedWords)")
                words = savedWords
                savedWords.removeAll()
                print("savedWords array after clear all: \(savedWords)")
            } else {
                saveInitialWordValues(to: defaults)
            }
            print("Words is : \(words)")
            print("Number of words: \(words.count)")
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func saveInitialWordValues(to defaults: UserDefaults) {
        switch chosenLanguage {
        case "german":
            words.append("Bear::Baissespekulant::0")
            words.append("Camel::Kamel::0")
            words.append("Cow::Rind::0")
            words.append("Fox::Fuchs::0")
            words.append("Goat::Geiß::0")
            words.append("Monkey::Affe::0")
            words.append("Pig::Schwein::0")
            words.append("Rabbit::Karnickel::0")
            words.append("Sheep::Schaf::0")
            //words.append("::")
            print(words)
            defaults.set(words, forKey: "germanWords")
            print("At end of saveInitialGermanValues")
        case "french":
            words.append("Bear::l'ours::0")
            words.append("Camel::le chameau::0")
            words.append("Cow::la vache::0")
            words.append("Fox::le renard::0")
            words.append("Goat::la chèvre::0")
            words.append("Monkey::le singe::0")
            words.append("Pig::le cochon::0")
            words.append("Rabbit::le lapin::0")
            words.append("Sheep::le mouton::0")
            //words.append("::")
            print(words)
            defaults.set(words, forKey: "frenchWords")
            print("At end of saveInitialFrenchValues")
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        chosenLanguageLoad()
        loadInitialValues()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    @objc func addNewWord() {
        // create our alert controller
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add new word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        // add two text fields, one for English and one for French or German.
        ac.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "English"
        }

        ac.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "\(self.chosenLanguage.capitalized)"
        }

        // create an "Add Word" button that submits the user's input
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Word", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // pull out the English and French words, or an empty string if there was a problem
            let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
            let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
            let zeroTimesWrong = "0"
            // submit the English and French word to the insertFlashcard() method
            self.insertFlashcard(first: firstWord, second: secondWord, third: zeroTimesWrong)
        }

        // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
        ac.addAction(submitAction)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

        // present the alert controller to the user
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func insertFlashcard(first: String, second: String, third: String) {
        guard first.count > 0 && second.count > 0 else { return }

        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: words.count, section: 0)

        words.append("\(first)::\(second)::\(third)")
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)

        saveWords()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete  = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            self.words.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            // delete item at indexPath
        }

        let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Edit word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            // add two text fields, one for English and one for French
            ac.addTextField { textField in
                let word = self.words[indexPath.row]
                let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let englishWord = split[0]
                textField.placeholder = "\(englishWord)"
            }

            ac.addTextField { (textField) in
                let word = self.words[indexPath.row]
                let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let foreignWord = split[1]
                textField.placeholder = "\(foreignWord)"
            }

            // create an "Add Word" button that submits the user's input
            let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Word", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                // pull out the English and French words, or an empty string if there was a problem
                let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
                let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text ?? ""

                guard firstWord.count > 0 && secondWord.count > 0 else { return }
                // edit item at indexPath
                self.words.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.words.insert("\(firstWord)::\(secondWord)", at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()

                self.saveWords()
            }

            // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
            ac.addAction(submitAction)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

            // present the alert controller to the user
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
        }

        edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return [delete, edit]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //print("In cellForRowAt function")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)

        let word = words[indexPath.row]
        if word != "::" {
            let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")

            print(split[0])

            cell.textLabel?.text = split[0]

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""

            //print(cell)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.detailTextLabel?.text == "" {
                let word = words[indexPath.row]
                let split = word.components(separatedBy: "::")
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = split[1]
            } else {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        words.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        saveWords()
    }

    func saveWords() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.polyglot") {
            defaults.set(words, forKey: "\(chosenLanguage)\(wordString)")
        }
    }
}
```